# Expectation of function in a lognormal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, logarithms, expected-value

I have the function Y = e^X, which is a log-normal distribution. I am supposed to find its expectation in terms of mu and sigma. Would definitely appreciate being helped through this as I'm quite stumped!

Comment: What is stumping you?

Comment: Not sure how to start off the problem. I know what the expectation for X is, but am not sure how to find an expectation of a function of X as opposed to just X.

Comment: *The law of the unconscious statistician* says $\mathbb{E}(g(X))=\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f_X(x) dx$, for continuous RVs $X$ with PDF $f_X(x)$ and there is an analogous statement for discrete RVs but with sums replacing integrals and PMFs replacing PDFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean that $X$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, and you want $\mathbb E[Y]$ where $Y = e^X$.
We can write $X = \mu + \sigma Z$ where $Z$ has the standard normal distribution (mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$).  Thus 
$$ \mathbb E[Y] = \mathbb E[e^{\mu + \sigma Z}] = 
e^\mu \mathbb E[e^{\sigma Z}]$$
Now either look up the Moment generating function of the standard normal distribution, or do the integration
$$ \frac{e^\mu}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\sigma z} e^{-z^2/2}\; dz$$
by completing the square in the exponential.

Comment: I believe it is ln(X) is normal with that mean and standard deviation, not X itself.

Comment: If you wanted $Y = \ln(X)$, why did you write $Y = e^X$?

Comment: The function is Y = e^X. The distribution is not normal, however, but log-normal, which (if I understood correctly), was defined as ln(X) ~ N(mean, standard deviation)

Comment: The distribution of $X$ is normal, the distribution of $Y$ is log-normal.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. Thanks!